# Девятисмысленная фраза?

Tags: значения

Утверждают, что фраза "Один мужик решил заработать, и заработал" имеет девять смыслов.

Мне удалось найти четыре смысла:

1. Решил начать работать и начал работать.
2. Решил начать работать и заработал денег.
3. Решил заработать денег и начал работать.
4. Решил заработать денег и заработал денег.

Где кроются ещё пять смыслов?

Comment: заработать 2. Разг. Получить, приобрести что-л. неприятное (обычно о болезни).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заработать носит еще смысл заработать что-то неприятное (болезнь, наказание и т.п.). 
Здесь можно найти еще несколько смыслов.

5. Решил начать работать, но в результате заработал себе болезнь.
6. Решил заработать денег, но заработал себе неприятности
7. Решил заработать (найти) себе неприятности, но нашел работу
8. Решил заработать (найти) себе неприятность, но получил деньги
9. Решил заработать себе неприянтости и он именно их и заработал.

Comment: Разве можно сказать про болезнь просто "заработал" без указания, что именно болезнь?

Comment: @BrainsFeeder Смысл фразы часто зависит от контекста применения. Т.е. елси у нас был разговор о человеке который хотел заработать денег, но переоценил свои силы и в результате лежит в больнице с инфарктом, то не нужно дополнять исходную фразу. И так становится ясно что имеется в виду. А собственно фраза является как бы итогом обсуждения.

Comment: Приведённая фраза имеет контекст, который имеет - то есть, без контекста.

Comment: @BrainsFeeder любая двухсмысленная, а тем более девятисмысленная фраза имеет конкретный смысл только в контексте. Без контекста у нее куча смыслов. Как пример фраза "Он это заработал", может иметь несколько смслов. Но пока мы не узнаем контекст мы не  сможем сказать о каком именно смысле идет речь.

Answer (score 2):

Набор значений фразы состоит из комбинации значений слова "заработать". "Заработать" означает:
1. Заработать денег
2. Начать работу
3. В переносном смысле - заработать неприятности, например, удар по лицу в тёмной подворотне: "Ну всё, ты заработал!"
4. Неприятности разные бывают, заработать можно и насморк, и 
5. Прыщ на носу.
Получается 5 в квадрате = 25. К слову сказать, можно придумать фразу, дающую бОльшую степень, например: "Решил заработать и заработал, но получилось только заработать" - хотя, справедливости ради, там смыслов меньше, чем 5^3 = 125, ибо есть противопоставление.
Обновление: Как поправил Avi Gordon, значений у слова "заработать" всё-таки 3, так как 3, 4 и 5 пункты равны

Comment: №3 = №4 = №5. Таки 3^3=9.

Comment: Уговорил, чёрт языкастый.

Comment: :) Errata: 3^2=9

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам еще смысл: мужик был андроидом. Сперва не работал (не функционировал), а потом решил заработать. И заработал.

Comment: Это первый смысл.1.Решил начать работать и начал работать.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to play with 'заработать' as 'утомить' (to make someone tired).